# Table indent not working

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, itemize

So I have the following code setup:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{resize to}[a4paper,landscape]
%\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[a4paper]
%\usetheme{Singapore}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
%\usefonttheme[?options?]{structuresmallcapsserif}
%\definecolor{beamer@blendedblue}{RGB}{203,140,55} % changed this
\definecolor{beamer@blendedblue}{RGB}{0,102,102} % changed this
%\definecolor{beamer@blendedblue}{RGB}{0,153,153} % changed this
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts} %To get the accents aligned correctly, albeit in Computer Modern Roman
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{table}[h]
            \centering
            \begin{tabular}{p{6cm}|p{6cm}}
                \centering{Nonlinear Systems} & \centering{Linear Systems}\\
                \hline
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item More realistic
                    \item Usually difficult to analyze and design
                    \item Can have multiple equilibria
                    \item System stability may depend on initial condition
                    \item Limit cycle (self-sustained oscillations)
                    \item Bifurcations (number of equilibrium points and their stability nature may vary with parameter values)
                    \item Chaos (very small difference in initial conditions can lead to large difference in output as time increases)
                    \item Frequency and amplitude can be coupled
                \end{itemize}
            \end{tabular}
        \end{table}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

I am also getting an error:

`Misplaced \noalign. \end{frame}`

What I am trying to do is to make an `itemize` environment on both columns, and for some reason, when I `\centering` the `Linear Systems` part, I get that error. Moreover, the itemized list that was supposed to be on the left column gets moved to the right. How to fix it?

Comment: Don't use centering like that. Use \multicolumn{1}{c}{...} instead to center the column headers.

Comment: Might if you write up the solution?

Comment: I currently don't have the time to, but I will do later.

Comment: No worries, I am not in a rush.

Comment: @leandriis, I followed your solution, but the vertical line doesn't appear for the top row. How to fix it?

Comment: `\multicolumn{1}{c|}{...}` when used in the left column or `\multicolumn{1}{|c}{...}` when used in the right column should both horizontally center the contents of the cell as well as add back in the proviously missing line. (I'm not used to vertical lines in table, so I overlooked that in my original comment. Sorry for that.)